# Using Python see if Table exists

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have to connect to an Oracle database and see if a table exists. While I can get a list of the tables, I'm having trouble seeing if the table I'm looking for is in the list. Some tables have associated table which I'll have to join on, some do not, thus I have to check.

What is in my list: ('NYSDOH_CI_EI_HOSPITAL',)

```
sql =   "SELECT table_name FROM all_tables"

cur.execute(sql)

searchstr = 'NYSDOH_CI_EI_HOSPITAL'
p = re.compile(searchstr)

#create data array to load in SQL results in.
ciDataSet = []

cxRows = cur.fetchall()    
for i in cxRows:
    #print i  # list of tables
    if p.match(str(i)):  
        print  i
```

It doesn't find it, even if I use a wildcard.

Comment: Is your string in the result from `print cur.fetchall()` ?

Comment: If not, what is being returned if you print cxRows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve on the syntax of @vaichidrewar, you could simplify the fetch loop to:

```
for tabname, in cur:
    if p.match(str(tabname)):
        print(tabname)
```

But it's going to be more efficient to do the reg exp matching in the query:

```
sql = "select table_name from all_tables where regexp_like(table_name, :tn, 'i')"
searchstr = 'EMP'

cur.execute(sql, (searchstr,))
for tabname, in cur:
    print(tabname)
```

The 'i' option does a case-insensitive match.  You can adjust the regexp as you like.

Comment: I first tried putting it into the query, but I couldn't get it working nor find a good example. You have a clear example that worked well.

Answer (score 3):

fetchall() returns a list of tuples. 
So when you do

```
for i in cxRows:
```

'i' is of type tuple. In your case, this tuple will have only single value. You can access it using i[0] and match it with p. 
Currently you are converting a tuple to string so regular expression will not match.

Corrected code:

```
   sql =   "SELECT table_name FROM all_tables"

    cur.execute(sql)

    searchstr = 'NYSDOH_CI_EI_HOSPITAL'
    p = re.compile(searchstr)

    #create data array to load in SQL results in.
    ciDataSet = []

    cxRows = cur.fetchall()    
    for i in cxRows:
        #print i  # list of tables
        if p.match(str(i[0])):  
            print  i
```

Comment: It's better to do the reg exp matching in the query.